# Are not the real numbers a concrete category?

Tags: category-theory

I'm reading Awodey's Category Theory book. He says that the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, regarded as a poset category, is small but not concrete; and that **Pos** is concrete but not small. However, every small category is concrete via its Cayley representation. In what way the author says that $\mathbb{R}$ is not concrete and **Pos** is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On page 7, Awodey explains the term "concrete category" as follows.

> The categories that we have been considering so far are examples of what
> are sometimes called concrete categories. Informally, these are categories in
> which the objects are sets, possibly equipped with some structure, and the
> arrows are certain, possibly structure-preserving, functions ...

This is the notion of concreteness that Awodey uses to in the paragraph you're asking about.

The category $\mathbb{Pos}$ is a concrete category because its objects are structured sets (posets), and its morphisms are structure preserving (in this case monotone) functions.

$\mathbb R$ is not a concrete category because its morphisms are not functions but abstractly derived from an order relation.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that a concrete category is a category $C$ together with a faithful functor $F : C \to Sets$.

The category of posets has an obvious forgetful functor that forgets the partial order and remembers only the set. This makes it into a concrete category.

$\mathbb{R}$ as a poset does not have an obvious forgetful functor.

However, it turns out that every poset can be made into a concrete category.

Let $(P, \leq)$ be a poset (or more generally, a preorder). Then consider the functor $F : P \to Sets$ sending all objects to $1$ and all arrows to $1_1$. This is a faithful functor.

So $\mathbb{R}$ can be made into a concrete category, but not in an especially natural or insightful way.

Comment: I think that's not the meaning of concrete that Awodey is referring to here. The original meaning of concrete category is "category of structured sets and structure-preserving functions". the thing with the faithful functor is an attempt at an "abstract" (i.e. invariant under iso/equiv) reformulation of concreteness, but in a sense that misses the point of the whole concept.

Comment: @JonasFrey Then consider the category whose objects are of the form $(1, r)$ where $r$ is a real number, where 1 is a 1-element set, and where the map $1 \to 1$ is structure-preserving for $(1, r) \to (1, s)$ iff $r \leq s$. This is an isomorphic category to $\mathbb{R}$ as a poset.

Comment: Yes, but you're proving that R is concrete, and I think the original question is in which sense R is *not* concrete

Comment: @JonasFrey: I believe the accepted definition of the term "concrete category" is the one Mark is using. I agree with you that it is conceptually unsatisfactory in some ways. But then the category of posets is conceptually unsatisfactory in many ways.

Comment: I think this discussion could benefit from taking care of the distinction between properties and structure. This answer takes concreteness to be a property - a category $C$ is concrete if *there exists* a faithful functor $C\to\text{Sets}$. But presumably (I haven't read it) Awodey's book takes concreteness to be extra structure - a concrete category is a category $C$ *equipped with* a faithful functor $C\to\text{Sets}$. If you take the structure definition then it's not enough for such a faithful functor to exist - you have to specify a particular functor to meet the definition.

Comment: Awodey's point that the question is about is that R is not concrete because it's not on its face a category of sets and functions (though it is equivalent to one).

Comment: @Nathaniel Precisely, which is why I specified that any poset "can be made into a concrete category", not that every poset is one.